# Vue webpack devServer proxy prepending fetch url with vue-router params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, fetch

I have vue3 project using a webpack devServer proxy and keep getting a 404 when running a fetch to an api due to the url being prepended with an incorrect value. This only occurs on pages that are using vue-router params.

example page url is -
http://localhost:8081/edit/206

correct fetch url should be -
http://localhost:8000/api/enquiries/getenquiry/206

actual fetch url -
http://localhost:8000/edit/api/enquiries/getenquiry/206

**fetch command -**

```
        let response = await fetch(`api/enquiries/getenquiry/${id}`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
```

**vue-router -**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import NewEnquiries from '../views/enquiries/NewEnquiries.vue'
import EditEnquiry from '../views/enquiries/EditEnquiry.vue'
import MailboxesView from '../views/system/mailboxes/MailboxesView.vue'

const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'home', component: HomeView },
  { path: '/new', name: 'new', component: NewEnquiries },
  { path: '/edit/:id', name: 'editenquiry', component: EditEnquiry },
  { path: '/mailboxes', name: 'mailboxes', component: MailboxesView }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

**vue.config.js -**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const AgentKeepAlive = require('agentkeepalive');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
                agent: new AgentKeepAlive({
                    maxSockets: 100,
                    keepAlive: true,
                    maxFreeSockets: 10,
                    keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                    timeout: 6000000,
                    freeSocketTimeout: 9000000 // free socket keepalive for 9000 seconds
                }),
                onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                    const key = 'www-authenticate';
                    proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**What works -**

adding the following pathRewrite to remove the prepended "edit" acts a workaround but obviously not a good solution going forward. Where am i going wrong here?

```
    pathRewrite: { '^/edit': '' }
```